# Getting image from the url as null values

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata

Hi I have a problem in getting images from urls. Im getting those urls from a web service and then load images 1 by 1 those are attached with each url.

```
-(void)downloadMyfriendReqImage:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
    if (path.row<[arrayPendingRequests count]) {
        NSString *str=[[arrayPendingRequests objectAtIndex:path.row]valueForKey:@"USERIMAGE"];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]]];

        if (img==nil) {
            img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
        }

        [dicPendingReqImages setObject:img forKey:str];
        [tblFriendRequests performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:@"TAG_29" waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

This is the way that I used to load images. But the problem is some images are not getting. `img` become null value. But I have the same application in android. It loads all those images perfectly. What is the problem for this.. Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the result of the NSData request, before transforming it into an image. Could be you are getting a timeout from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the rply. If it taking timeout req why it not affect to the android one?

Comment: It might be android uses a proxy, which reacts faster? Did you have a look at the content of NSData?

Comment: @iDia Instead of `dataWithContentsOfURL`, use [`dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:) and then you can look at `NSError` to discover if something went wrong, and if so, what.

Comment: its getting null value. NSData is null

Comment: and the error message derived from the method provided by Rob?

Comment: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.): (null) This is what I got

Comment: what is the content of [NSURL URLWithString:str]

Comment: (lldb) po url
(NSURL *) $0 = 0x0f06f370 http://nishzone.uphero.com/MMWS/upfiles/English%20top%2010.jpg  @MartinMandl-This is the ulr

Comment: if you have access to the server, have a look at its log. Or just try to add http:// in front of the string

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)downloadMyfriendReqImage:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
    if (path.row<[arrayPendingRequests count]) {
        NSString *str=[[arrayPendingRequests objectAtIndex:path.row]valueForKey:@"USERIMAGE"];
        //ADDED LINE
        str=[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]]];

        if (img==nil) {
            img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
        }

        [dicPendingReqImages setObject:img forKey:str];
        [tblFriendRequests performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:@"TAG_29" waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

I think your url contains some characters like spaces which `NSURL` cannot read, to make it work you need to add encoding to the string, I think it should work this way.. Check the code for `//ADDED LINE`.

Comment: but it works when I paste it on the browser. Its not containing any white spaces or something

Comment: I tryed. But still same :(

Comment: try to add NSLog to the url and see.. and special character might also create problem..

Answer (score 0):

**Try THis:**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
NSString *str=[[arrayPendingRequests objectAtIndex:path.row]valueForKey:@"USERIMAGE"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (error) {
    // handle error
    return;
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // do something with the data
 UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
});
});
```